# Puppeteer schedule action at specified time

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to schedule Puppeteer's async functions, picture the following:

```
await page.type("field", "somedata");
// calculate specific timestamp
setTimeout(() => { await page.click("#submit") }, delay);
```

I need to prepare multiple forms in "paralell" as in I cannot halt until that specific timestamp passes, the objective is to prepare those forms and then submit them at a specific timestamp. It is required for two forms that calculate a similar timestamp to submit within 10ms after another.

I am hoping for a way for this to happen without creating my own event loop in the main function. Also, if in such a loop I am awaiting other pupeteer functions, I would surely miss the exact timestamps. Am I out of luck?

Answer (score 2):

Your code should work if you mark your function as async like this:

```js
setTimeout(async () => { await page.click("#submit") }, delay);
```

But your code has the problem, that the setTimeout is not a Promise, so an action like `await page.close()` (which I assume would come next) will fire before the timeout is executed.

It would be better to do it like this:

```js
await page.type("field", "somedata");
await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, delay)); // waits delay milliseconds until the promise is resolved
await page.click("#submit");
```

Comment: Thanks, I think the first solution will do. The second one would block the whole app until the timestamp, if I understand correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use puppeteer's own promisified timer without awaiting for delay and click:

```js
await page.type("field", "somedata");
page.waitFor(delay).then(() => { page.click("#submit"); });
```